# A dusty shop, with a white space invaders game machine?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I can't remember much about this scifi short story (part of a book of stories).
It must be at least 30 yrs since I read it.

There was a space invader machine which was white with a spherical white control and no other buttons. I think it was in a dusty old shop with a sinister shop keeper.  The main character was a boy (I think) and he had some kind of disquieting/disturbing experience when playing the game. It might have been that it connected him to an alien planet?

Comment: Is there any other detail at all that you can remember?  Do you remember the main character(s) or even whether it was a book, movie etc?

Comment: Sorry should have said it was a book. I think it was part of a short story collection. And it was sci fi. The main character was a boy o think and he had some kind of disquieting/disturbing experience when playing the game. It might have been that it connected him to an alien planet? Maybe? Sorry it's so vague

Comment: I can't place it. You might want to have a read through [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if the checklists help you come up with any more details.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I found it in "[Space Invaders](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?770289)" and in a compilation of short stories by Nicholas Fisk, published in 1984 called *[Sweets from a Stranger and Other SF Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33990)*. Unfortunately it's not the right one.

[A review](https://vector-bsfa.com/author/niallh/page/21/):

> No prizes for guessing what this one’s about. Jason is addicted to the games at his local arcade, to the point of stealing from his mother and bunking off school to play them more. He’s good, too, and the games — which are of course self-aware — appreciate his skills. They chat like proto-Minds, their transcripts presented with Fiskian translations. They are confident in their superiority (“players are only players. They are not real like us”) but not un-affectionate:

....

> Indeed, when Jason hits a losing streak, one of the machines finds a soft spot and lets him win. Surely, the machine thinks this guarantees his return. But it does not.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the right one. I'll keep looking. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a book by Douglas Hill called, *[Have Your Own Extraterrestrial Adventure](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?712843)* (1983), ISBN 0-09-930700-6

[image: Front cover of Have Your Own Extraterrestrial Adventure]

The Douglas Hill who wrote the 'Exiles of Colsec' and 'Legionary Quartet' amongst others.

Suggesting this because I only read a few pages of this in a book shop. It was a short novel book. In short, a boy playing a space combat computer game was really interacting with an alien civilization. '... every time we kill him he comes back.'